# Beamer, bug color title

Tags: beamer

There is a bug in beamer which is quite annoying, and I don't know how to solve it properly. In my theme, the title of a frame is always in white:

[image]

However, if the example block is empty, or if it contains only a list, the frame title is black, which makes it hard to read:

[image]

Do you know why, and how to solve this problem? I tried to add at the beginning a tilde,but it adds an empty line that I don't like...

Thank you.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}     
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My great title}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Exemple}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item b
    \end{itemize}
  \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which version of beamer do you have? Everything's okay for me with TL 2017 pre-release. Please provide also your MWE for the second slide. Just to make sure you don't have any typo (thought I don't think you have).

Comment: That works fine in TeX Live 2017, `beamer` version 2017/08/22 v3.43. Which version do you have? (Add `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}` and look at the `*File List*` at the end of the `.log` file.)

Comment: How are you compiling? pdflatex or something else? which tex dtrsibution do you have? Which beamer version? This is what I get with TL2017 and pdflatex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrrFt.png

Comment: Indeed, I updated tex, and now everything works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @tobiasBora Great! Could you please write a short answer that updating solved the problem?  As this questions seems to repeat regularly I like to keep this around as a reference for future questions and not close it as "solved by update".

Answer (score 4):

As sztruks (and others) pointed it out, an upgrade of my LaTeX distribution solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with Debian 9.2 and no option to upgrade.
A quick hack waiting the new version is to put

```
\begin{frame}{\color{white}title}
```

in all slides where this occurs...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is not an answer as an answer should give details and best a MWE.